# jquery show hide not working in mobile

Tags: jquery, web-applications, mobile

I'm designing a mobile friendly version of my site and everything seems to be working fine, but I can't click on the links inside the div that shows after click function shows that div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);



$("#business").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $("#business_open").show();
    $("#menu_open").hide();
});

$("#menu").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $("#menu_open").show();
    $("#business_open").hide();
});

});
```

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>

<div id="business">
  <span>Title</span>
</div>

  <div id="business_open">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<div id="menu">
  <em>m</em>
</div>

  <div id="menu_open">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="selected" href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: My links are inside of #business_open and #menu_open

Comment: Show us your actual HTML please.

Answer (score 0):

Your events might be getting assigned before the DOM has finished loading. You can get around that by wrapping them in a jQuery ready function, the shorthand of which looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#business").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(".wrapper, #business_open").show();
        $("#menu_open").hide();
    });

    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(".wrapper, #menu_open").show();
        $("#business_open").hide();
    });

    $(".wrapper").click(function(){
        $(".wrapper, #business_open, #menu_open").hide();
        $('#business, #menu').removeClass('on');
    });
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

 document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);



 $("#business").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('on');
  $("#business_open").show();
  $("#menu_open").hide();
 });

 $("#menu").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('on');
  $("#menu_open").show();
  $("#business_open").hide();
 });

});
That's what my js looks like now?
In regards to the </a>.. I just forgot those in the above code, I have them in mine.

Comment: @Josh - don't ever try to put multi-line code in a comment.  If you want to communicate some code after posting your question, add it to the end of your question and then refer to it from a comment.  Multi-line code is only legible when formatted properly in a question or answer, not in a comment.

Comment: Was trying to point out i already have document ready function in my JS file.